# SQL Query to remove duplicated data and take single column sum

Tags: sql, .net

I have the following table resulted from

```
SELECT m.MedName as [Medicine],m.MedSellPrice as [RetailPrice],m.MedType as [Type],
       m.SoldQuantity as [Sold],m.Quantity as [Available],b.BillAmount as [Total Bill],b.BillDate
FROM BillMedicine AS bm LEFT JOIN
     Medicine AS m  
     ON bm.MedicineID=m.id LEFT JOIN
     Bill AS b
     ON bm.BilIID = b. ID
```

but now I want to remove the repeated rows except the Sum of 'TotalBill'.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    m.MedName AS [Medicine],
    m.MedSellPrice AS [RetailPrice],
    m.MedType AS [Type],
    m.SoldQuantity AS [Sold],
    m.Quantity AS [Available],
    SUM(b.BillAmount) AS [Total Bill]
FROM BillMedicine AS bm
LEFT JOIN Medicine AS m
    ON bm.MedicineID = m.id
LEFT JOIN Bill AS b
    ON bm.BilIID = b.ID
GROUP BY
    m.MedName,
    m.MedSellPrice,
    m.MedType,
    m.SoldQuantity,
    m.Quantity;
```

Note that for the billing date, the two "duplicate" records you have highlighted have different dates.  It is not clear which date, if any, you want to report here.  I have omitted this column.

Comment: i understood your query but it also throws exception

Comment: Then the problem is with the original query you showed us, not my answer.

Comment: I applied condition (where b.BillDate<='somedate') before the 'group by'. is it write?

Comment: @MuamberKhan Yes, if your intention is to restrict to only bills occurring before a certain date.

Answer (score 0):

**GROUP BY** Is Best Option for DUPLICATE DATE Removed & SUM.

```
Select Column1,column2....., SUM(Total) as Total  From Tablename Group BY column1,column2
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want most (or all) columns from `m` and then the sum from another table.  One method is a lateral join or correlated subquery:

```
SELECT m.*,  -- or whatever columns you want,
       (SELECT SUM(b.BillAmount)
        FROM BillMedicine bm JOIN
             Bill b
             ON bm.BilIID = b.ID
        WHERE bm.MedicineID = m.id
       )  as [Total Bill]
FROM Medicine m  ;
```

I suggest this approach for several reasons.

- This is often more efficient than an outer aggregation.
- You have `LEFT JOIN`s but they do not look correct.  I suspect you want to start with the `Medicine` table.
- You are including a date/time in the results, but clearly that is not appropriate when combining multiple rows.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i am gona implement and see

Comment: i tried the query you mentioned above but it throws the exception...(Invalid object name 'Medicine'.)

Comment: i am including the datetime column because i need to pick up those records which meet the FromDate and ToDate criteria